# Does the FedEx shipping API have a SOAP endpoint?

Tags: web-services, api, soap, wsdl, fedex

Does the FedEx shipping API have a SOAP endpoint? I'm unable to find the WSDL endpoint.

Comment: aah, why is this off-topic?  Why is it ok to ask about some God forsaken version of an API that hasn't been updated in 5 years but not ok to ask about FedEx API?  It is ok to ask about Google Maps API but not FedEx API? Where's the line?

Comment: I was wondering why its off topic myself :( I was only looking for the soap endpoint that is bad? :(

Answer (score 10):

Their site has changed since the other 2 answers here.

The most direct answer is that they do not have a classic WSDL endpoint, where you just get a URL, Add Service Reference and go.

Instead they have you download a zip file which contains a wsdl file which you then use locally - pretty odd. That wsdl file changes name over time, as does the zip, with every version - but the current file is at:

https://images.fedex.com/templates/components/apps/wpor/secure/downloads/wsdl/201607/standard/RateService.zip

My guess is you can get at it without logging in given the images subdomain, likely a CDN.

Once that link dies here's how you currently navigate their obtuse Developer section, which they'll probably also change again:

http://www.fedex.com/us/developer/

Click [FedEx Web Services](http://www.fedex.com/us/developer/web-services/index.html) on the left

Under the unclickable "Document and Downloads" part of the page, click [Move to Downloads](https://www.fedex.com/us/developer/web-services/process.html?tab=tab1)

Scroll to the bottom - there's a weird table with service names like "Quote Rates." Each time you expand a row, the header row will have some Download text stuffed into it. Clicking "WSDL" gets you the zip file.

Not the worst process for getting a simple WSDL I've seen but, they're definitely in the running.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it would appear so.

http://www.fedex.com/us/developer/solutions.html

Comment: thanks, ahh i think i will have to email them cant seem to find the soap endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if they have the WSDLs available remotely, but they do provide the WSDLs for download on their **Technical Resources** page on their [developer solutions](http://www.fedex.com/us/developer/solutions.html) page, to which you need a login with FedEx.

Comment: Creating an account is free, its all they ask you to access their Technical Resources.

Comment: I tried to create an account, but their website does not work! so much for that :( I think nomore FedEX!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this endpoint

https://wsbeta.fedex.com:443/web-services

i found it from here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57176378/5374995

Or you can find endpoint on the bottom of WSDL file  with name="RateService"